# SWt : what is the color of a Control's border?

Tags: java, swt

I want to draw a top border on a Composite with such code :

```
final Composite c = new Composite(parent, SWT.NONE);
        c.setLayout(new FormLayout());
        c.addPaintListener(new PaintListener(){

            @Override
            public void paintControl(PaintEvent e) {
                int x = c.getBounds().x;
                int y = c.getBounds().y;
                e.gc.setForeground(SWTResourceManager.getColor(0));
                e.gc.drawLine(x, y-23, x + c.getBounds().width, y-23);
            }

        });
```

but how can I make the border has same look & feel as the default borders? and how can I get the right Y coordinate of the composite ?

I want the composite only has a top border, is there any other way to do so ?

Answer (score 2):

Check [Detect system settings snippet](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0280__SWT/Detectasystemsettingschange.htm), which shows, how could you get system colors.

In your case

```
Color borderColor = display.getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_WIDGET_BORDER);
```

Comment: SWT.COLOR_WIDGET_NORMAL_SHADOW will make the border looks like default.

Answer (score 1):

1)

You could use 3 Composites for this.
1 Composite in which the other 2 are placed.

Like:

MainComposite

- TopComposite (Which is the border and very small)
- CenterComposite (In Which your information is placed)

2)

You could use a LayoutData for the inner Composite, with spacing informations. But than you would see the Parent Composite at the top and the bottom.

Take a look at

- GridData.verticalIndent
- GridData.heightHint

Answer (score 1):

This is a non-trivial issue :-)

Have a look at UIForms in Eclipse - especially `org.eclipse.ui.forms.widgets.FormToolkit.BorderPainter`...